# Why do rational functions in $\mathbb{P}^n$ have to be a ratio of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, projective-space, rational-functions

To have a well defined homogeneous polynomial $f:\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$, we require that it is homogeneous so that $f(x)=f(\lambda x)=\lambda^{\deg f} f(x)=f(x)$ (so that it is well defined on projective space).

In various texts (e.g. [Sutherland's lecture notes on Elliptic Curves](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2022/), [Harris Geometry of Algebraic Curves](https://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/UIUC/curvesHarris.pdf)) a rational function $g:\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is defined to be the ratio of homogeneous polynomials $f$ of the **same** degree. Intuitively I assume this is to make sure $g$ is well defined.

However, let $g=f/h,$ where $f,g$ are homogeneous polynomials on projective space of some arbitrary degrees $F,G$. Then, $g(x)=g(\lambda x)=f(\lambda x)/h(\lambda x)=\lambda^{F-G}f(x)/h(x)=g(x)$. This does not require that $F=G$.

**Question:** Why then is it required that $f$ and $h$ have the same degree for $g=f/h$? Am I wrong in my analysis somewhere, or is there a different reason for the definition, or am I wrong in interpretation of the definition?

Edit: or do we consider $g$ as a function to affine space?

Comment: $g(\lambda x)=g(x)$ seems like a nice property to have when working in a projective space.

Comment: But it retains this property even if $F\neq G$.

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent right. Multiply $h(x)$ by $x^{F-G}$ and you have rewritten $g$ as the quotient of two polynomials of the same degree. So probably convinience.

Comment: I thought it was something like that, but there seem to be consequences of this; see Example 3.6 of Harris' curves linked above: let $F,F'$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree $d,d'$ and consider the divisors $V(F),V(F')$, then as divisors $V(F)-V(F')=(F/F')$. Then it says V(F), V(F') are linearly equivalent iff F, F' have the same degree (iff F/F' is rational). So the notion has some consequences that seem to supersede convenience.

Comment: @TejasRao you have it by definition but $g(x)$ has it as a computational property. It's self-normalizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a ratio of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree defines a function $\mathbb P^n \to \mathbb P^1$, not $\mathbb P^n \to \mathbb P^n$.  For the latter, the usual description is as an $(n+1)$-tuple of coordinate maps, each of which is a homogeneous polynomial of the same degree, not all vanishing at any common point.

For example, consider $\mathbb P^1$ with projective coordinates $[x : y]$.  If $f, g \in k[x, y]$ are homogeneous of degrees $F, G$ and $h := [f : g]$, then we have:
\begin{align*}
h([\lambda x : \lambda y]) & = [f(\lambda x, \lambda y) : g(\lambda x, \lambda y)] \\
& = [\lambda^F f(x, y) : \lambda^G g(x, y)],
\end{align*}
which agrees with $[f(x, y) : g(x, y)]$ if and only if $F = G$.

I think your mistake is in passing between affine and projective coordinates.  If $[f : g]$ is a map to $\mathbb P^1$ as above, we can view it in affine coordinates as a ratio $f/g$ of homogeneous polynomials, where the zero locus of $g$ is sent to the point at infinity.  But affine coordinates are not defined up to scalar multiplication, so $\lambda^{F-G} f(x)/g(x)$ is not the same thing as $f(x)/g(x)$.