# Rational map of projective varieties is determined by homogeneous functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Reading some material on rational maps between projective varieties, I've seen that some people define them differently. For example, some people define a rational map $f : \mathbb P^n \to \mathbb P^m$ by $f(x) = [f_0(x), \dots, f_m(x)]$ for homogeneous functions $f_0,\dots,f_m$ of degree $d$. However, I have also seen it defined by $f(x) = [f_0(x), \dots, f_m(x)]$ for $f_0,\dots,f_m \in k(\mathbb P^n)$ instead.

Are these two definitions equivalent? Namely, if we have $f_0,\dots,f_m \in k(\mathbb P^n)$ can we produce homogeneous functions $f'_0, \dots, f'_m$ all of degree $d$ where $f(x) = [f'_0(x), \dots, f'_m(x)]$ as well (and vice versa)?

Comment: What did you try? The only thing you could ever do does in fact work, so...

Comment: @HankScorpio i believe the only step would be to try and maybe show that some $f_0 \in k(\mathbb P^n)$ is homogeneous? i'm not quite sure as i'm quite new to projective geometries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do rational functions in $\mathbb{P}^n$ have to be a ratio of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409449/why-do-rational-functions-in-mathbbpn-have-to-be-a-ratio-of-homogeneous-po)